# Format column of cells to date format

Tags: excel, vba, date, converters

I want to convert all cells in column A to date format "yyyy-mm-dd" and I use this code below

```vb
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
    .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
End With
```

But not all cells are converted.

> [image: Result]

[Link to file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aG4gvGlE8mywl45_CWfZphJo8figcxDt/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Dates are (formatted) numbers. It looks like you're dealing with text-that-looks-like-a-date. Changing the format won't convert the underlying value.

Comment: Try `FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)`